# Use only One malloc for a complete linked list

Tags: c++, list, malloc, singly-linked-list, allocator

I'm writing a program that  will use linked list for allocating memory.

The goal is to reduce the number of call to the `malloc()` function.

For that I have imagine the following allocate function : (head (`Slot<T>*`) and free_slots(`int`) are part of the allocator)

```
 inline T* allocate(size_t length)
{
    if(free_slots == 0){
        head = (Slot<T>*) malloc(length * sizeof(Slot<T>) * NBR_NEW_OBJECT);
        free_slots = NBR_NEW_OBJECT;
    }

    T* result = &(head->data);
    head = static_cast<Slot<T>* >(head->next);
    return result;
}
```

I have define the `Slot`structure :

```
template <typename T>
struct Slot{
   T data;
   Slot* next;
};
```

But the second time we enter the allocate method (it is ok the first time) i've got a segfault.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `head = static_cast<Slot<T>* >(head->next);` where is `next` intiialized?

Comment: Why don't you use standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)? BTW, you might have a linked list of arrays...

Comment: It should be allocate with the big malloc in the previous iteration

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++?  Why not use [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new)?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what @BasileStarynkevitch refers to, whether to abandon the effort and use a std container instead, or to use a std container instead of manually mallocing. I would strongly recommend using a vector instead of a manual malloc.

Comment: Since for most uses `operator new` adds useless overhead to `malloc`, it isn't that absurd to call malloc directly in low-level allocators.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: What useless overhead would that be, exactly?

Comment: You can only allocate one memory area if you know the quantity of items in the list at compile time.  One of the reasons for using multiple dynamic memory allocations is for when the quantity of objects can't be determined at compile time.  So why the restriction?

Comment: @ChristianHackl https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/new_op.cc?view=markup one function call, a test if the argument is 0, a test if malloc returned 0. Those aren't always useless, just often. Also, gcc knows about malloc and can optimize accordingly, while it does not know that operator new is special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the good way was to initialize all the `Slot->next` fields before
so the correct implementation should be :

```
inline T* allocate(size_t length)
{

    if(free_slots == 0){
        head = (Slot<T>*) malloc(length * sizeof(Slot<T>)  * NBR_NEW_OBJECT);
        free_slots = NBR_NEW_OBJECT;

        for(int i = 0; i < NBR_NEW_OBJECT; i++)
                head[i].next = reinterpret_cast<Slot<T>* >(&head[i+1]);

    }

    T* result = &(head->data);
    head = reinterpret_cast<Slot<T>* >(head->next);
    free_slots--;
    return result;
}
```